# RegEx Does Not Match Properly on HTML Content

Tags: php, regex

there is  a php program using regex but not show any thing in output ! 
whats wrong ?

```
<?php
$data='<div id="bodyContent" class="grid_16 push_4"> 

<form name="cart_quantity" action="http://iran-micro.com/product_info.php/products_id/1407/action/add_product" method="post"> 
<div> 
  <h1 style="float: left;">xxxxxxxxxxx</h1> 
  <h1>rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr<br /><span class="smallText">zzzzzzzzzz</span></h1> 
</div> 
' ;

 preg_match('/<h1 style="float: left;">(?P<cost>.*?)</h1>.*?<h1>(?P<name>.*?)<br />/s',      $data, $matches);

echo $matches['name'];
echo $matches['cost'];
 ?>
```

Comment: Please don't put emoticons and multiple exclamation marks in your question title...

Comment: Start by simplifying the problem.  Does a simple `echo "Hello";` work?  Does a *simple* regex work?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth that indicates that it's going to be a really simple question, so I don't see the problem with it :D

Comment: @Pekka, you're wrong actually unless he updated the code.

Comment: I could be wrong here, but doesn't stuff like `<br />` close the regex (the `/` character)?

Comment: @Frits: It doesn't indicate that to me.  To me, indicates someone who can't be bothered to write complete sentences, let alone a helpful question title.

Comment: @Oli to my knowledge I've already solved it, so it's bit of a moot argument :P

Comment: @Frits you're right, seems to be my mistake. (Unless he updated within the 5 minute window.)

Comment: Minor point. We can't see the contents of the <h1> tags, but if name and cost are in each, it seems likely to be incorrect semantics.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `/` in your regex if you use it as the delimiter (which you do). If not the "regex-part" stops at the first `/` and then the following invalid modifier `h` appears. And for that reason you get the following warning:

```
Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'h' in test.php on line 11
```

For regex with html code I usually use `~` as delimiter because `~` is very uncommon in html code (unlike `/`).